# Bash "diff" utility showing files as different when using a regex Ignore

Tags: regex, bash, diff

I'm trying to use the bash utility "diff" that is documented here: http://ss64.com/bash/diff.html.  Note that I'm using a windows-ported version of the bash utility, but that shouldn't make any difference.

I have two files, regex_test_1.txt and regex_test_2.txt that have the following contents:

regex_test_1.txt:

```
// $Id: some random id string $ more text

text that matches
```

regex_test_2.txt:

```
// $Id: some more random id string $ more text

text that matches
```

I am trying to diff these files while ignoring any lines that fit this regex:

```
.*\$(Id|Header|Date|DateTime|Change|File|Revision|Author):.*\$.*
```

However, when I run diff and tell it to ignore lines matching this regex using the -I argument, this is the output:

```
C:\Users\myname\Documents>diff -q -r -I ".*\$(Id|Header|Date|DateTime|Change|File|Revision|Author):.*\$.*" regex_test_1.txt regex_test_2.txt
Files regex_test_1.txt and regex_test_2.txt differ
```

I expect that it should find no differences (and report nothing).  Why is it finding these files to be different?

Comment: `diff` is not a "bash utility".  It's a utility that can be called from bash, but other than that there's no real connection between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `diff` uses basic regex syntax, wherein certain regex metacharacters lose their special meaning:

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?, +, {, |, (, and )` lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions `\?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \)`.

This should work:

```
.*\$\(Id\|Header\|Date\|DateTime\|Change\|File\|Revision\|Author\):.*\$.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for giggles, add -b to your diff.  Ignore differences in white space.