# Issue using regex option with 'diff'

Tags: regex, shell, diff

dI have been trying to do a very similar thing as this... [Bash "diff" utility showing files as different when using a regex Ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520179/bash-diff-utility-showing-files-as-different-when-using-a-regex-ignore)

and have been at it for hours but no luck.

I am convinced the -I option does not work.  Below is a test using the example given from the other issue.

Note: I am using the standard version of 'diff' that comes with RHEL6, and the -I is included in the man page so no reason to believe it shouldn't work but it doesn't.  Any help or direction would be apprecitated

```
[toernerg@uschi12devwom27: ~] $ cat testfile1
// $Id: one
data

[toernerg@uschi12devwom27: ~] $ cat testfile2
// $Id: two
data

[toernerg@uschi12devwom27: ~] $ diff testfile1 testfile2
1c1
< // $Id: one
---
> // $Id: two

[toernerg@uschi12devwom27: ~] $ diff -I '.*\$\(Id\|Header\|Date\|DateTime\|Change\|File\|Revision\|Author\):.*\$.' testfile1 testfile2
1c1
< // $Id: one
---
> // $Id: two

[toernerg@uschi12devwom27: ~] $ diff --version
diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.1
```

Comment: the formatting did not come out correctly.  Let me just try pasting without formatting...

Comment: Your sample input file does not contain a literal `$` after the colon.  Perhaps you did not mean to escape the `$` in the regex, but wanted to match the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex requires dollar-signs in two places, but your input only has the first one. Fix that, and it works:

```
[user@host ~]$ cat testfile1
// $Id: one
data

[user@host ~]$ cat testfile2
// $Id: two
data

[user@host ~]$ diff -I '.*\$\(Id\|Header\|Date\|DateTime\|Change\|File\|Revision\|Author\):.*\$.' testfile1 testfile2
1c1
< // $Id: one
---
> // $Id: two
[user@host ~]$ diff -I '.*\$\(Id\|Header\|Date\|DateTime\|Change\|File\|Revision\|Author\):.*' testfile1 testfile2
[user@host ~]$ diff --version
diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.1
```

(By the way, the leading and trailing `.*` are not actually needed.)

Answer (score 0):

To work in your example case, try:

```
diff -I '\$\(Id\|Header\|Date\|DateTime\|Change\|File\|Revision\|Author\):'
```

Comment: uhhggg, OK that does work for that example (I copied it straight from the other issue and didn;t catch the second $).  That said, on to the REAL issue.

Comment: Here is a new real example which my use case uses xml files.  Perhaps is has something to do with it being xml??? and it's not reading properly?

Comment: [toernerg@uschi12devwom27: ~] $ cat test1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">

<!-- 20121018.12: WombatDists GENERATED FILE - DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- GSD: /sw/gsd/md_wombat/linux64/2.39.0 -->

-- xml data here --
</config>

[toernerg@uschi12devwom27: ~] $ cat test2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">

<!-- 20121017.12: WombatDists GENERATED FILE - DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- GSD: /sw/gsd/md_wombat/linux64/2.40.0 -->

-- xml data here --
</config>

Comment: [toernerg@uschi12devwom27: ~] $ diff -I '.*GENERATED.*' test1.xml test2.xml
3,4c3,4
< <!-- 20121018.12: WombatDists GENERATED FILE - DO NOT MODIFY -->
< <!-- GSD: /sw/gsd/md_wombat/linux64/2.39.0 -->
---
> <!-- 20121017.12: WombatDists GENERATED FILE - DO NOT MODIFY -->
> <!-- GSD: /sw/gsd/md_wombat/linux64/2.40.0 -->

Comment: @gt: You should probably edit your initial question, rather than trying to post XML files in comments. :-P